# c# sql cannot convert varchar to int (Found a work around)

Tags: c#, sql, insert, int, varchar

im trying to insert some data into a sql server and the code worked fine untill i added the @instel at the end. when i added that i got the error "Error converting data type varchar to numeric." even if i leave the textbox empty.

i had it as a textbox but since i got the error i tried to have it as a variable but it still did not fix the issue. the code works for the REL thats to be inserted and that is also a int. also the database and textbox properties of REL and @instel are the same. i also tried to make the variable a int but it did not change anything. if anyone knows why this is and could help me out it would be appriciated.

```
 SqlCommand slMEVO_NAW = new SqlCommand(@"insert into NAW(REL,NAAM,BTW_CODE,TAV,STR,PL,LAND,PLBOX,TAAL,COUNTRY_C,TEL,FAX,EMAIL,XMAS,TEL2,STR1,INSTELINCL,INCOTERMS,PRODDAT,INSTEL) values('" + this.Txtbx_RelNmmr.Text + "','" + this.Txtbx_Bedrijf.Text + "','" + this.Txtbx_BtwCode.Text + "','" + this.Txtbx_Tav.Text + "','" + this.Txtbx_HuisAdres.Text + "','" + this.Txtbx_PstCde.Text + "','" + this.Txtbx_Land.Text + "','" + this.Txtbx_PstBs.Text + "','" + this.Txtbx_Taal.Text + "','" + this.Txtbx_LndCode.Text + "','" + this.Txtbx_Telnmmr.Text + "','" + this.Txtbx_Fax.Text + "','" + this.Txtbx_Email.Text + "','" + this.Txtbx_Xmas.Text + "','" + this.Txtbx_telnmmr2.Text + "','" + this.Txtbx_BezAdres.Text + "','" + this.TBX_Instelkstn.Text + "','" + this.Txtbx_Incot.Text + "','" + this.TBX_PrdctDtm.Text + "','@INSTEL' );", Connectie.connMEVO_NAW);
            slMEVO_NAW.Parameters.Add("@INSTEL", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Txtbx_InstelKsten.Text;
```

FIX
it seems that after i changed it to all parameters it only gives the error if the textbox is empty so i just make the program set the text to 0 before it does the query right now

Comment: SQL injection alert.  You need to start by modifying your SQL query so it uses ALL parameters, not concatenated strings.

Comment: Don't quote it;  `+ ", @INSTEL);` - but *much more importantly* parameterize all the other values as well

Comment: i tried to remove the ' around the @instel but it still didnt work and i do know about changing the rest to variable but im still trying to have it work before i do that.

Comment: @maam27 You're just making it harder by using that "style". Any single quote in one of the text boxes will screw up the query. Not only is using parameters safer, it's also easier.

Comment: im working on changing that atm

Comment: @Grant Winney
it still gives me the same error then it just changes int for decimal, it only needs to save full numbers no decimal so int would make more sence to me on this but i tried that before.

Comment: what is the data type of @instel in your database?

Comment: @ako its set to numeric but REL is also set to numeric and that one works fine if i remove the instel

Comment: try to convert your input to @instel to int

Comment: if you are using a stored procedure then let us see its code

Comment: Run this and post results so we can see table structure please. `exec sp_columns NAW;`

Comment: thanks for trying to help me but i have a way that it works now, so its not longer needed.

Comment: @maam27 Can you post your solution so others can benefit from it

Comment: i edited the main post but my way of working around it was just to make set the text of the textbox to 0 if its empty since for a reason it only gave the error when empty after i changed it to parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i stated in the main post after a edit i found a way to work around the problem

FIX it seems that after i changed it to all parameters it only gives the error if the textbox is empty so i just make the program set the text to 0 before it does the query right now

Answer (score 0):

The type of field in your table might be as Integer or Numeric, change to Varchar.